# How does one manually ensure tmux starts up with bash completion?

Tags: bash, tmux, autocomplete

The problem here is potentially a cross-platform issue (I am running a MacOSX Brew-installed `tmux` with a Brew-installed `BASH` and bash completion.

When I first installed `tmux`, a new open window operated exactly like a native linux tmux session with a fully initialized bash environment. Bash completion, in particular,  worked.

---

Lately, bash completion has stopped functioning upon opening a new window. I had the "trivial" workaround of:

```
$: tmux new -s foo
$: vi 
(from vi)
:sh
$: echo "bash completion is now working again"
```

But, after a few weeks this has qualified a fix.

---

I see this problem as being an X or Y question: either I fix `tmux` on MacOSX (and learn how `tmux`, `bash`, and `bash-completion` work under the hood a little bit more),

-- or --

I figure out how to have `tmux` run `vi` and send the ":sh" keys to the `vi` window whenever a window is created.

This latter option is easier on the one hand, but has drawbacks that will cause me to wind back around to solution one: I will have to `CTRL-D` + `SHIFT[colon]q!` + `CTRL-D` every time I want to kill a window (which is often).

---

My question relates to the first option:

How do I govern or control `tmux` on start-up and/or window-specific start-up so that I can manually initialize `bash` and `bash-completion` with whatever proper (or hackish) fix I need on the mac to restore the typical working order of new `tmux` windows?

Comment: does bash completion work again if you run `exec bash` instead of forking a shell from `vi`?  how about `exec bash -l`?  i.e. does it make a difference if the shell is a "login" shell?

Comment: @cas yes this works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the default shell in tmux explicitly.

```
set-option -g default-shell /bin/bash
```